# MySQL question about using between operators

Tags: mysql, between

I am learning MySQL and saw a project related to e-commerce and customer behaviour and want to follow it along.

However, when calculating the number of unique customers retained on the second day, the original author used a different approach and got a different result.

The code is below:

```
select count(distinct user_id) as first_day_customer_num from userbehavior
where date = '2017-11-25';-- 359 unique customers counted and retained on the first day

select count(distinct user_id) as second_day_customer_num from userbehavior
where date = '2017-11-26' and user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM userbehavior
WHERE date = '2017-11-25');-- 295 unique customers counted and retained on the second day
```

I used the between method for date and here is my code below to calculate the number of unique customers retained on the second day:

```
select count(distinct user_id) as trial from userbehavior 
where date between '2017-11-25' and '2017-11-26'; -- 450 unique customers counted
```

Could I ask why is our result different and which part did I do wrong?

Thank you so much for your help and support, really appreciate it.

Comment: Your select query counts `user_id` for both 25th and 26th , so it will output more data .Whereas the author has first filtered out `user_id` that were present on the 25th and then checked whether those id's were retained on 26th .

Comment: That's not what between does - 3rd query will count customers who have transacted on '2017-11-25' OR '2017-11-26'; and is equivalent to date >= '2017-11-25' and  date < = '2017-11-26';

Comment: Try this `select count(distinct user_id) as trial from userbehavior 
where date >= '2017-11-25'  and  date <  '2017-11-26'`